VMWare Workstation Pro interfers with physical KVM switch
So this is probably a rare and possibly unique issue.
I use a STARTECH:SV211KUSB KVM for my desk setup at home for switching between my personal device and my work laptop.
Now, on my work Laptop I have VMWare Workstation Pro installed (current v17.6.1 build-24319023) to run some local VMs for testing and various things.
When I try and use a VM on my home setup the KVM button switches to the other machine somehow. I think the KVM is trying to use the USB device. At first I wasn't getting any prompts, but now SOMETIMES I do get asked do I want to install the Keybopard onto the VM or the host. I select host but shortly after it will happen again.
I have to physically press the KVM computer button to switch it back. and if I'm using a VM it will eventually happen again. Very annoying.
Is there any way I can block VMWare's access to the USB KVM device?
